# Close Event in Kendo Datepicker fire many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, jquery-ui-datepicker, kendo-datepicker

I have created a template in my grid:

```
template: '#if(IniReal != ""){# <div class="text-center">#= IniReal #</div> # } else {#<input class="fechaReal" />  #} #',
```

in this template a datepicker is created when the element of my arrangement comes empty

```
$(".fechaReal").kendoDatePicker({
                            format: "dd-MM-yyyy",                            
                            parseFormats: ["dd-MM-yyyy"],
                            change: vmSeg.Cambio,
                            close: vmSeg.Cerrar
                        });
```

the problem lies in the Close event after firing for the first time, the next time it fires, it does it twice, and so on, I just want the Close event triggered once and it does not fire repeatedly

This is my event Close

```
 vmSeg.Cerrar = function (e) {
                $("#ActiSeguimiento").on("focusout", ".k-datepicker", function (e) {
                    vmSeg.grid = $("#ActiSeguimiento").data("kendoGrid");
                    vmSeg.dataItem = vmSeg.grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));                    
                    vmSeg.dataItem.IniReal = vmSeg.NuevaFecha;
                    return false;
                });
            }
```

and this is my event Change:

```
vmSeg.Cambio = function(e) {
                vmSeg.NuevaFecha = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(this.value()), "dd-MM-yyyy");

            }
```

What is wrong in my event Close?

Comment: I could not replicate the issue at my side - would you please try to isolated it in a [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/) so that it could be expected deeper.

Comment: hello. [link](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Ulises_Tmtz/aBoKOj)_italic_ **bold** `This` is my code in a dojo

Comment: [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Ulises_Tmtz/aBoKOj) .This is my code in a dojo. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have inspected the dojo that you provided and it seems like the issue is caused by declaration of the 'focusout' event that is hooked on every close not in the Kendo widget. When I removed the decalration of the 'focusout' event the scenario worked correctly. The close was triggered correctly at my side yet the 'focusout' was triggered many times. In such case I would recommend you to define as [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/aMUBu/2) it separately so that it triggers only once.

Comment: The reason of the 'focusout' is because i want recover the row and the selected value of the calendar addit to the row. And save data more later.

Comment: Another way is to set the 'focusout' event only to the datepicker wrapper  use the open event too and to remove it as for example in this [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/oHIGUV/2)

Comment: Thanks!!!. Set the 'focusout' event in the wrapper solve my problem. Now i can continue with the flow